# Newbie on mobile login for a web application

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, oauth-2.0

I'm have developed a web application for an appointment system. The clients/patients log in to the system for an appointment and an admin controls the appointments.

I'm planning to expand the system by developing a mobile app where clients/patients will also be able to log in for an appointment using the mobile app.

I'm new to mobile dev and not familiar with how sessions are handled in mobiles/tablets. I already created a simple CRUD using ionic frameworks but without the login/logout process yet. My questions are:

1. Do I need Oauth2.0 to implement the mobile login/logout? As I understand on Oauth, they are used if you plan to authorize other apps to access your data. In my case, there is no other application except the mobile app I'm planning to implement.
2. The current login/logout in my web app is handled by '**sessions**' and I read that '**tokens**' are used to handle this process on mobiles/tablets. Are 'tokens' only the solution?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: out of curiosity what stops you to use what you have for desktop with mobile? any particular obstacles?

Comment: Mobiles are handy and convenient. Patients can use the system anywhere even on public and I'm planning also to incorporate Notification in mobiles.